# Integral: product of Bessel functions

Tags: integration, special-functions, bessel-functions

I work on a project and I am blocked on the question to determine the auxiliary density $\Omega_{\mu}(r)$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{+\infty}\left(I_{n+\mu}(r)\right)^2\Omega_{\mu}(r)dr=\frac{n!}{(n+\mu)(2\mu)_n}.
\end{equation}
where $I_{n+\mu}(.)$ is the Bessel function. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this the modified Bessel function of the first kind?

Comment: Yes $I_{n+\mu}(.)$ is the modified Bessel function of first kind.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio $(x)_n$ is the Pochhammer which can be defined using the gamma function $(x)_n=\frac{\Gamma(n+x)}{\Gamma(x)}$

Comment: @PatrickCherche: ok, but what about the other point? Should we replace $\Omega$ with $\Omega_\mu$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Actually $\Omega$ has to depend of $\mu$ but not of $n$: This is the Hausdorff's moment problem